# Twilio start recording when two attendant are connected?

Tags: twilio, recording

I am using Twilio in group type mode (not peer-to-peer), due to I need to perform a recording.
However, I need that the recording begins when both callers are connected, is possible?
Now the recording begins when for the first caller begin.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By default Twilio Video will record all participant tracks for the entire time they are connected. To change what is being recorded at any time you need to use the [recording rules API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recording-rules).

If you only want the recording to start when two participants have joined, then you should set up your room with rules that initially exclude all tracks from being recorded. You can do this by [creating the room using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#post-list-resource) and providing the following `RecordingRules`

```js
[
  {
    "type": "exclude",
    "all": true
  }
]
```

Then when your second participant joins, [update the recording rules by making a request to the `RecordingRules` subresource of the Room](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recording-rules?code-sample=code-update-room-recording-rules-to-start-recording-all-participants&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json), changing them to:

```js
[
  {
    "type": "include",
    "all": true
  }
]
```

Comment: Let me know if it works out for you!